# Hacer que los eventos sucedan por separado, en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

En CSS es muy simple usar `hover` y darle una animación a botones por separado, pero quiero hacer esto con javascript y estoy seguro que hay algo que no estoy considerando.

> Ejecute este código y al hacer `hover` en la caja verde notará que aparece un punto en ambas cajas.

Yo entiendo que al usar `.querySelectorAll()` me resulta un arreglo de todas las clases que coinciden, pero ¿cómo hago que se "interpolen" con el otro arreglo de clases? Para que me resulte las animaciones por separado.

> Para dejar claro: quiero que al hacer `hover` sobre una caja verde aparezca solo su animación sin que también aparezca en la otra caja verde.

```js
let hijo = document.querySelectorAll('.hijo');
let etiqueta = document.querySelectorAll('.etiqueta');

etiqueta.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener("mouseover",() => {
      hijo.forEach(l1=>{
        l1.classList.add("edd1");
        });
   });

    link.addEventListener("mouseleave",() => {
       hijo.forEach(l1=>{
        l1.classList.remove("edd1");
        });
   });
});
```

```css
body{
display: flex;
}
.box{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: solid 1px black;
}
.etiqueta{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
left:50px;
top:50px;
background: green;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
}
.hijo{
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: blue;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
transform: scale(0); /*desaparece el elemento hijo*/
}
.edd1{ /* la class que se agrega y se quita*/
background-color: red;
transform: scale(1); /*reaparece el elemento hijo con el mause al centro*/
};
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que tu variable **hijo** contiene todos los elementos con la clase `.hijo` de tu **DOM**, por lo que al sucederse los eventos vinculados a `.etiqueta`, va ha animarse todos.

A ti lo que te interesa es animar solamente el elemento `.hijo` que tenga como padre el elemento `.etiqueta` que dispara el evento. Es por eso que lo que hice fue declarar la variable **hijo** dentro del `forEach` en el que recorres las etiquetas y este hijo buscarlo en el elemento **link** en vez de en el **document**.

```js
let etiqueta = document.querySelectorAll('.etiqueta');

etiqueta.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener("mouseover",() => {
      let hijo = link.querySelectorAll('.hijo');
      
      hijo.forEach(l1=>{
        l1.classList.add("edd1");
      });
   });

    link.addEventListener("mouseleave",() => {
      let hijo = link.querySelectorAll('.hijo');
    
      hijo.forEach(l1=>{
        l1.classList.remove("edd1");
      });
   });
});
```

```css
body{
display: flex;
}
.box{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: solid 1px black;
}
.etiqueta{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
left:50px;
top:50px;
background: green;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
}
.hijo{
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: blue;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
transform: scale(0); /*desaparece el elemento hijo*/
}
.edd1{ /* la class que se agrega y se quita*/
background-color: red;
transform: scale(1); /*reaparece el elemento hijo con el mause al centro*/
};
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pensaba que al declarar una variable let, solo debías preocuparte por el scope; pero ahora entiendo que si lo declaras afuera este no tiene el evento, y cuando lo declaras adentro de link este tiene el evento lo que automáticamente resuelve el problema . woo!!! gracias por iluminarme!!!...

Answer (score 1):

Como ha dicho @phpMyGuel el problema está en que seleccionas todos los hijos de todos los padres. Otra forma de resolverlo es usando el contexto (`this`) del elemento que esta ejecutando el evento. Osea buscar los hijos (`querySelectorAll('.hijo')`) de `this`.

```js
let etiqueta = document.querySelectorAll('.etiqueta');

etiqueta.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {

    this.querySelectorAll('.hijo').forEach(l1 => { // <-- this es el padre
      l1.classList.add("edd1");
    });

  });

  link.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {

    this.querySelectorAll('.hijo').forEach(l1 => {
      l1.classList.remove("edd1");
    });

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.etiqueta {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.hijo {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.edd1 {
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(1);
}

;
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
    <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
    <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Si queremos usar el `this` no podemos usar las funciones flecha, tenemos que escribir `function`.